# HTML select tag text direction

Tags: html, css, right-to-left, bidi

There is a way to create a right-to-left text-direction `select` tag in HTML?

The following works in IE, but in Firefox only align the text and in Chrome nothing...

```
<select dir="rtl">
<select style="direction: rtl;">
```

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox I think you'll also need to set [`bidi-override`](http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/unicode-bidi/):

```
<select dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">
    <option style="direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;">test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me on Chrome 8.x dev. I'm sure it is a bug that's already fixed.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjxv6/

Comment: Most common users are using Chrome 7. there is no solution? and what about Firefox?