# Setting rtl/ltr attribute in option element, Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internationalization, bidirectional

Firefox and Chrome support adding `dir` attribute to an option element, i.e.

```
<select>
    <option dir="rtl">some text</option>
    <option dir="ltr">some text</option>
</select>
```

This, however, does not seem to work in Internet Explorer 7 or 8. Did anyone manage to get some kind of a solution for this?

Comment: Related, but strangely stating the opposite, that it works in IE but not Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058326/html-select-tag-text-direction

Comment: on <select> things work fine, however, I want to specify <select> as rtl (in order to get the layout straight) and then the <option> ltr.

Comment: Perhaps you want one option in one direction and another in opposite. Well, it seems that the only browser which supports such scenario is Firefox... I've tried Opera, Chrome, IE, FF and Safari and results are not very promising.